# How do I get to all of the command line options described inside of clang?

Tags: clang, llvm

When I look through the LLVM and clang code base I see all sorts of command line options that I can't seem to get to. For example, inside of AliasAnalysisCounter.cpp I see:

```
static cl::opt<bool>
PrintAll("count-aa-print-all-queries", cl::ReallyHidden, cl::init(true));
static cl::opt<bool>
PrintAllFailures("count-aa-print-all-failed-queries", cl::ReallyHidden);
```

When I try to get at them from the command line:

```
~ robertzeh$ clang++ -count-aa-print-all-failed-queries foo.c
clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-count-aa-print-all-failed-queries'
```

The clang version reports:

```
~ robertzeh$ clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
```

What am I doing wrong or misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the options defined in various transformation passes directly. Try doing `clang++ -mllvm -count-aa-print-all-failed-queries foo.c`

Answer (score 2):

A good place to snoop on options clang (the driver) and clang `cc1` (the frontend) accept is:

- `include/clang/Driver/Options.td`
- `include/clang/Driver/CC1Options.td`

Comment: That's a great place to see the top level options, but how do I use the ones that I see scattered in the various transform passes?